# Python Twisted TCP/IP Connection

Tags: python, tcp, twisted, telnet, linode

I have a Linode account and I am trying to communicate using telnet with a basic TCP/IP server written in Python (Twisted), installed in a linode with ubuntu lts:

```
import os
from twisted.internet import protocol, reactor

class Echo(protocol.Protocol):
    def dataReceived(self, data):
        self.transport.write(data)

class EchoFactory(protocol.Factory):
    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return Echo()

port = 5000
reactor.listenTCP(port, EchoFactory(), interface="<my linode's ip>")
reactor.run()
```

I thought I could just do `telnet <my linode's ip> 5000` and be able to send and receive messages from the server, like when I test the app locally with `telnet localhost <some port>`
Could you please forward me to some sort of guide or reference to help me accomplish this? 
I reckon I need to configure something on the linode where the server app is installed? Is it to hard? Thanks.

Comment: `reactor.listenTCP(port, EchoFactory(), interface='<my linode's ip>')` is not valid Python - the quote after `linode` must be escaped.

Comment: This seems like a linode sysadmin question, rather than a programming question?  Maybe it would be a better fit for one of the other stackoverflow sites.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with linode, but my guess is that you need to open the port 5000 on the firewall to be able to connect. You can verify that by trying the same telnet command from the ssh session on your linode instance. If it works from there its definitely the firewall.

Answer (score 0):

This code is correct. May be your problem in firewall, you can test this code via connection to localhost?
telnet localhost 5000
And, can you change  to 0.0.0.0 ?